# Laravel 5.5 related models connection issue

Tags: postgresql, laravel, octobercms

Quick question here. As of Laravel 5.4 related queries utilize the parent's connection. I have OcoberCMS data sitting on the main connection and program specific data on another connection; Same DB different schema (PostgreDB). I set the connection on models within my program as i cant go and update the connection string on the October models. This is an issues since I have program data utilizing the October file model in order to handle attachments. In this case the eloquent looks for "system_files" on the parent relation connection. Any plausible work-around besides holding all data in one schema.

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time parsing your question. Take a look at the comments on https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9355

Comment: You are getting my question based on your link...as i read through that before i posted my question. The situation here is that the related model is outside of my scope. As in it is a model directly from OctoberCMS i cannot edit it without losing my changes once i update the framework. My model/table is sitting on a different schema that the OctoberCMS default models/tables.